# How to use OData API key with custom integrated API .NET 4.8 MVC controller?

Tags: sitecore-api, mvc

- https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/api-keys-for-the-odata-item-service.html
- https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sitecore-api-key-throttle-series-2-md-arifuzzaman-arif/

Referring back to these links I tried using `[RequiredApiKey]` however it's never getting recognized as a class attribute on the controller:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RequiredApiKey` attribute is in a separate package and namespace `Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Security`. I can't see from your screenshot whether you've added a reference to `Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore`, and if you have this in your using declarations:

```
using Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Security;
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much for the help, you're quiet right however it required also to install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core

Comment: @MohamedAbbas I think you might have misread that, as far as I can see it requires Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors (CORS not Core).

Comment: I think you might be right I can't recall the case now, however I think you're correct